# How to multiply hours past 24h

Tags: google-sheets, time, formula, spreadsheet

I have a basic table to keep track and charge for my work. It`s working really well except that when the total hours reach 24h the formula takes "TIMEVALUE" as 0.

formula = TIMEVALUE(F4) * 24 *25

Hoe can I multiply let`s say 26:30 hours y 25$?

Thankas in advance

[image: Timetable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 26:30 hours and 1 hour costs 25$ you can do:

```
=VALUE(A1)*24*25
```

[image]

`VALUE` of a duration will give you the number of days. So for example, `24:00:00` will be `1` and `26:04:32.000` will be `1.086481481`. So as the formula above demonstrates, you can just multiply this by 24 to get the number of hours even if it goes above 24 hours.

[`VALUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220)

Answer (score 0):

[`TIMEVALUE` Returns the fraction of a 24-hour day the time represents.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350?hl=en)

One of the solutions would be calculating the total number of hours in `F4` with:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(TIMEVALUE(F7:F))*24)`